# Class.newInstance() how to use a method?

Tags: java, class, abstract-class

I created an abstract class as follows:

```java
abstract class Chance
{

   public void setTeams(SportEvent aSportEvent)
   {
      firstTeam = aSportEvent.getFirstTeam();
      secondTeam = aSportEvent.getSecondTeam();
   }


   private int totalPlayedGames()
   {
      int playedAtHome = firstTeam.getHomePlayedGames();
      int playedAway = secondTeam.getAwayPlayedGames();
      int playedGames = playedAtHome + playedAway; 
      return playedGames;
   }


   private int totalScoredGoals()
   {
      int homeScoredGoals = firstTeam.getHomeScoredGoals();
      int awayScoredGoals = secondTeam.getAwayScoredGoals();
      int scoredGoals = homeScoredGoals + awayScoredGoals; 
      return scoredGoals;
   }

   abstract double getChance()

   Team firstTeam;
   Team secondTeam; 
}
```

Then, of course, I have several classes with the method `getChance()`...

Now, I wanted to create a class in which I can get the result of `getChance()` of these new classes. I thought to use something like:

```
Class aClass = Class.forName(chanceClass....);
Object obj = aClass.newInstance();
```

and now I would like to use the 'getChance()' method.

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you have to use reflection or is that just an attempt? Do you not have an instance of the extending class? What is `chanceClass`?

Comment: @DwB That would not compile - `newInstance` returns an Object.

Comment: in addition to @bmorris591: `Chance c1 = new CustomChance(); Chance c2 = new YetAnotherChance(); double d1 = c1.getChance(); double d2 = c2.getChance();`

Answer (score 6):

You can simply cast it:

```
Chance obj = (Chance) aClass.newInstance();
double d = obj.getChance();
```

Comment: Even if chance is an abstract class ?

Comment: @Alpan67 Yes - you can try.

Comment: i get a NullPointerException ... but this is another mistake !

Comment: Better to use `Class.cast` and go via `Constructor`. (Or almost certainly much better, don't use reflection.)

Answer (score 3):

Without casting:

```
Class<? extends Chance> aClass = Class.forName(chanceClass....).asSubclass(Chance.class); 
Chance obj = aClass.newInstance();
double d = obj.getChance();
```

Comment: +1 good idea. Although it would not compile: `Class<? extends Chance> aClass = ...` would.